# Buttons are not respecting the Style defined in the parent's Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Edit: This wasn't a real issue, but Visual Studio being buggy. Reloading the project gave the expected result.

I have the following part in my interface:

```
<StackPanel
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="5"
        Orientation="Vertical">

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>


        <Button>
            Button 1
        </Button>

        <Button>
            Button 2
        </Button>

        <Button>
            Button 3
        </Button>

        <CheckBox>
            Checkbox
        </CheckBox>

</StackPanel>
```

Given the style definition inside the `StackPanel`, all the `Buttons`and the `CheckBox` contained should have a `Margin` of 5. Instead only the `CheckBox` gets the correct `Margin`:

[image: Layout output]

[image: Properties of a Button]
[image: Properties of a CheckBox]

Comment: I tested the XAML in your question and it put a 5 unit margin around the buttons. There must be more that you're not showing us. Have you tested that XAML snippet in isolation, in a new project?

Comment: I did try with a void project, worked as you said, loaded back my project and it was working... Basically it was a VS bug. Ty anyway

Comment: It wasn't a VS bug.

Comment: What you mean? Is it expected?

Comment: What reason do you have to assume it's a VS bug? VS bugs aren't unknown, but their code is far better tested and QA'd than yours is, so it's far more likely that the problem is in your own code. If you're the kind of programmer who didn't know to test your XAML in isolation, and who *does* immediately assume everything he doesn't understand is a compiler bug -- well, it's a near certainty that you're creating your own problems.

Comment: The same unmodified code gave two different results by just reloading the project. It's a small nuance but I'd still call it a bug

Comment: Sounds like a XAML designer state thing.

Comment: never trust what the designer shows you. run it and see it